# No github repositories in Azure's Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to deploy React project in Azure's Static Web App, but there are no repos if I link my Github account. When I check permissions for Azure Static Web Apps on Github, it has full control.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your `GitHub`=>`Settings`=>`Applications` => `Authorized OAuth Apps`, click on Revoke.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/PThTS1e.png).

Comment: Now In your Portal you will get an option to Authorize again.

Comment: In App Service => `Deployment Center`,Click on `Change Account` and Authorize the App Service again.

Comment: @Harshitha thanks, but there is no `Deployment Center`. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/zVhgSCR) is what I see.

Comment: Ok..In have shared you the App Service.Deployment option for Static Web App is available only while creating the static web app.In the same screen shot where you have shared initially, try to add change the account and check once.

Comment: Images [1](https://i.imgur.com/24wGQ5A.png) and [2](https://i.imgur.com/N6zn4nQ.png)

Comment: @Harshitha I granted permission again and logged out and logged in to azure. It didn't change anything. There are not repos in repositories list. Check my screenshots. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/7kCXMKm), [here](https://imgur.com/a/c1jNnFQ) and [here](https://imgur.com/a/eyryvJz)

Comment: You have something below the organization access.What is that ?

Comment: @Harshitha it's Azure Static Web Apps permission for whole organization. I granted it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding [static-web-apps-deploy](https://static-web-apps-deploy) into the project through Github UI. Then, I just needed to copy AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN from Azure project into Github project secrets.